# Question about basic optimization.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Seems like everytime I try to optimize the area of a rectangle given a certain perimeter, and make the area maximum, I end up with $l=w$ therfore implying that a square is more efficient in holding up area than a rectangle. Am I doing somthing wrong?

Comment: Could you give an example a

Comment: Maximize the area of a rectangle given 750ft of fence. I got $A=187.5*187.5$ as $l=w$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be the required perimeter. Then $2(l+w)=p \Rightarrow w=p/2-l$. The area is then:

$$
A(l) = l(p/2-l)
$$

You want to maximize the area, $A(l)$. $A'(l) = 0 \Rightarrow l = w$.